# Why does Rust's if-else AST use different types for then and else?

Tags: rust

I was writing Rust lint plugin when I found that Rust uses different types to represent the **then** (`Block`) and **else** (`Expr`) parts of an `if` statement in both `libsyntax::ast::ExprKind` and `librustc::hir::Expr_`.

I need them both to have common types.

Should I just use an explicit match over `hir::Expr_::ExprBlock`, or else part could be something else, and I need to make more smart comparison?

From [the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.10.0/src/librustc/hir/mod.rs#L869-L872):

```
// ...
pub enum Expr_ {
    // ...
    /// An `if` block, with an optional else block
    ///
    /// `if expr { block } else { expr }`
    ExprIf(P<Expr>, P<Block>, Option<P<Expr>>),
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Comment: I would guess that's because you _have_ to use a block (so a `{ /* code */ }` ) after an `if`, but you can omit the braces after an `else`. So you can write `if foo() { bar(); } else baz();` but you cannot write `if foo() bar() else baz()`.

Comment: @musicmatze that's very wrong. Rust does explicitly NOT allow you to leave off the braces after an else. Otherwise we're back in dangling else hell.

Comment: @ker ah, okay. I didn't knew that, so thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is so we can distinguish

```
if x {
    foo();
} else if y {
    bar();
}
```

from

```
if x {
    foo();
} else { // note the block
    if y {
        bar();
    }
}
```

The first has an `ExprIf` in the node of the else-`Expr` whereas the second has an `ExprBlock` containing a single `ExprIf`-expression.

Comment: Could you give (pseudo) code examples of how each of the two cases would look as a `ExprIf`?

Comment: @Shepmaster, first one is `ExprIf(_, Block(...), Some(ExprIf(...)))`, and the second one is `ExprIf(_, Block(...), Some(Block(..., ExprIf(...), ...)))`.